# Python-Turtle drawing recursive tree with 3 trunks

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a problem that, I have to make a tree with 3 trunks but the only tree I made was with 2 trunks. Here the example:

```
import turtle
import math
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.shape("turtle")
t.lt(90)

lv = 11
l = 100
s = 17

t.penup()
t.bk(l)
t.pendown()
t.fd(l)

def draw_tree(l, level):
l = 3.0/4.0*l
t.lt(s)
t.fd(l)
level +=1
if level<lv:
draw_tree(l, level)

t.bk(l)
t.rt(2*s)
t.fd(l)
if level<=lv:
draw_tree(l, level)
t.bk(l)
t.lt(s)
level -=1

t.speed(10)
draw_tree(l, 2)
```

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

The solution only seems a slight variation on what you already have.  Instead of just doing the left side then the right side, do left, middle and right.  Then adjust your angle, length and recursion levels until you get a pleasing result:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

LEVELS = 8  # recursion depth limit
MAX_LIMB_LENGTH = 120  # pixels
LIMB_ANGLE = 34  # degrees

def draw_tree(length, level):
    if level > LEVELS:
        return

    turtle.left(LIMB_ANGLE)
    turtle.forward(length)
    draw_tree(3/4 * length, level + 1)
    turtle.backward(length)

    turtle.right(LIMB_ANGLE)
    turtle.forward(length)
    draw_tree(3/4 * length, level + 1)
    turtle.backward(length)

    turtle.right(LIMB_ANGLE)
    turtle.forward(length)
    draw_tree(3/4 * length, level + 1)
    turtle.backward(length)

    turtle.left(LIMB_ANGLE)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.setheading(90)

turtle.penup()
turtle.backward(2 * MAX_LIMB_LENGTH)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(MAX_LIMB_LENGTH)

draw_tree(MAX_LIMB_LENGTH, 1)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]